# increase spacing vertically between two lines

Tags: html, css

I have plain html file as below

```
<div>
    THis is a looooooooong text. and it goes on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on 
    <br/><br/>
    2nd line
    <br/><br/>
    3rd line 3rd line 3rd line 3rd line 3rd line 3rd line 3rd line 
    <br/><br/>
    last line
</div>
```

What I want is increase the spacing between two lines

Right now I see text as below.

[image]

But what I want is increase the spacing between two lines by lets say 10px.

### [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hTPxJ/)

Any idea how to do that?

---

Space need to be brought as shown in below image. (for example i have considered only first line)

[image]

Comment: line height is good option please see me answer

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use line height to add space between to line :

**For example :**

```
div {line-height:25px;}
```

Answer (score 1):

Include the below css to give line height according to your requirement:

```
<style>
.small {line-height:10px;}
.big {line-height:200px;}
</style>
<div class="big">
    THis is a looooooooong text. and it goes on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on 
    <br/><br/>
    2nd line
    <br/><br/>
    3rd line 3rd line 3rd line 3rd line 3rd line 3rd line 3rd line 
    <br/><br/>
    last line
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using line breaks, use paragraphs and give them a margin.

CSS:

```
p {
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

Or use the `line height` on the `div` if you want all of the line spacing to be different even in the same paragraphs.

DIV:

```
div {
    line-height: 10px;
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/p6ywG/

Answer (score 0):

Just do something like that

HTML

```
<div>
    <p>THis is a looooooooong text. and it goes on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on </p>
    <p>2nd line</p>
    <p>3rd line 3rd line 3rd line 3rd line 3rd line 3rd line 3rd line </p>    
    <p>last line</p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
p{margin-bottom:10px}
```

Comment: After reading the edit, line height is a good option. However it's better to use <P> tags in this case instead of <br/>.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to style the line-height of only the br elements - there is away. (believe it or not)

```
br
{   content: "A" !important;
    display: block !important;
    margin-bottom: 3em !important;
}
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/hTPxJ/5/)**

Otherwise - line-height is the way to go as other answers have stated.

Answer (score -1):

**Thanks, We can add space between the Text and the Hoverbar by using .**

```
.homonhov:hover {
    border-bottom: 3px solid #FFFFFF !important; /*This will create a bar below it*/
    text-decoration: none !important; 
    position: relative !important;

 <a class="homonhov" href="index.php" style="line-height:35px;">HOME</a>
```